# conda list vs pip list differences in conda created environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

I am using conda version 4.5.11, python 3.6.6, and Windows 10.

I create a virtual environment using conda

```
conda create --name venv
```

When I check for installed packages

```
conda list
```

it is (as expected), empty.

But

```
pip list
```

is quite long.

Question #1: Why? - when I create a virtual environment using

```
python -m venv venv
```

the pip list is empty.

When I am not in an activated virtual environment, then

```
conda list
```

is also quite long, but it isn't the same as the pip list (* see follow up below)
In general, the pip list is a subset of the conda list. There is at least one exception ('tables' in the pip list, not in conda list) but I haven't analysed too closely. The conda list changes/displays some (all?) hyphens to underscores (or pip does the reverse). There also a few instances of versions being different.

Question #2: Why? (and follow up questions - can they be? and should I care?)

I was hoping to have a baseline conda 'environment' (that may not be the right word) -ie, the packages I have installed/updated into Ananconda/conda and then all virtual environments would be pulled from that. If I needed to install something new, it would be first installed into the baseline. Only when I need to create an application using different versions of packages from the baseline (which I don't envision in the foreseeable future) would I need to update the virtual environments differently.

Question #3: Am I overthinking this? I am looking for consistency and hoping for understanding.

-- Thanks. 
Craig

Follow Up #1: After installing some packages to my empty conda venv, the results of conda list and pip list are still different, but the pip list is much shorter than it was, but is a subset of the conda list (it does not include two packages I don't use, so I don't care)

Follow Up #2: In the empty environment, I ran some code

```
python my-app.py
```

and was only mildly surprised that it ran without errors. As expected, when I installed a package (pytest), it failed to run due to the missing dependencies. So ... empty is not empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. `conda list` vs `pip list`**

If all you did was *create* the environment (`conda create -n venv`), then nothing is installed in there, including `pip`. Nevertheless, the shell is still going to try to resolve `pip` on using the PATH environment variable, and is possibly finding the `pip` in the Anaconda/Miniconda **base** environment.

**2. `pip list` is subset of `conda list` outside env**

This could simply be a matter of `conda` installing things other than Python packages, which `pip` doesn't have the option to install.  Conda is a more generic package manager and brings in all the dependencies (e.g., shared libraries) necessary to run each package - by very definition this is a broader range than what is available from the PyPI.

**3. Overthinking**

I think this is more of a workflow style question, and generally outside the scope of StackOverflow because it's going to get opinionated answers. Try searching around for best practice recommendations and pick a style suited to your goals.

Personally, I would never try to install everything into my **base**/**root** Conda environment simply because the more one installs, the more one has dependency requirements pulling in different directions.  In the end, Conda will centralize all packages anyway (`anaconda/pkgs` or `miniconda3/pkgs`), so I focus on making modular environments that serve specific purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response merv.
I've got another related question I'll post to a new thread, it is along the same lines but a few steps down the process.